# Securing URL mapping with grails spring security core plugin

Tags: security, grails, plugins, spring-security

Just what the title says, I am trying to secure pages using Spring's security core.  Consider the following URL mapping (suppose that `home.gsp`, `page1.gsp`, and `page2.gsp` exists) :

```
"/"(view:'/home')
"/page1"(view:'/page1')
"/page2"(view:'/page2')
```

Now, consider the following settings inside the `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],   
    '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']        
]
```

If I understand correctly, I should be able to access home without any security and I should be directed to the login page when I try to access `/page1` or `/page2`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case.  I can still access page1 and page2 directly (e.g. http://localhost:8080/MyGrailsProject/page1).

However, if I try and use `@Secured` annotations through a controller's actions, the security kicks in (i.e. the request is redirected to the login page).  What seems to be the problem with my configuration?  How do I secure URL maps?

Comment: Have you tried to add '/home/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'] in interceptUrlMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap
```

It should be

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap
```

Note the s on plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It's default approach, to use annotations. But if you prefer to use url map, you have to set up:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
```

See docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#5.2%20Simple%20Map%20in%20Config.groovy

Comment: Yup, I already did the necessary configurations to `Config.groovy` and I still can access the pages directly.  I'm actually entertaining the idea of using controllers instead but I still like the idea of having all my configurations done in a single file (rather than having it embedded as annotations across my controller's actions).

Answer (score 1):

Order is important, You should have the most restrictive one at the top interceptUrlMap.

Comment: Patterns are always evaluated in the order they are defined. Thus it is important that more specific patterns are defined higher in the list than less specific patterns. This is reflected in our example above, where the more specific /secure/super/ pattern appears higher than the less specific /secure/ pattern. If they were reversed, the /secure/ pattern would always match and the /secure/super/ pattern would never be evaluated.